# UIView Autoresizing Resources

Tags: iphone, uiview, autoresize

I've been working on autoresizing a custom UIView and Apple has very little to say on this. What's more, based on SO feedback, Apple's documentation is actually wrong in some areas. Finally, even though there are six resizing components in Interface Builder and six for `setAutoresizingMask:` they don't seem to correlate at all. For example, setting the width spring in IB has a different effect from setting the `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` when rotating the device.

Are there any good resources for learning about how resizing works on the iPhone?

**Edit:**

I understand the basic concepts Apple uses such as contentMode, and I've read through the UIView documentation. I'm looking for something that explains a little more deeply what the IB settings do in terms of what's available in the SDK programmatically.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

setting the `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`, is equivalent to setting the width spring, plus both the left and right struts in Interface Builder (the struts mean that the edge is *not* flexible). If you wanted to replicate the behavior of only setting the width spring, but not the left and right struts, you would have to set `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`

Comment: Another way to word it: The two inner lines specify active autoresizing flags if red (as you'd expect) but the 4 outer lines specify active autoresizing if grey (the opposite of what you'd expect).

Answer (score 11):

I found this post helpful in understanding iOS autoresizing.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling

Comment: one more useful article.. http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html

Answer (score 2):

From Apple:

> ... specify the value of this mask by combining the constants described in
>   UIViewAutoresizing using the C bitwise OR operator. Combining these
>   constants lets you specify which dimensions of the view should grow or
>   shrink relative to the superview. The default value of this property
>   is UIViewAutoresizingNone, which indicates that the view should not be
>   resized at all.
>
> ... For example,
>   suppose this property includes the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth and
>   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin constants but **does not include
>   the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin constant,** thus indicating
>   that the **width of the view’s left margin is fixed** but that the view’s
>   width and right margin may change. Thus, the view appears anchored to
>   the left side of its superview while both the view width and the gap
>   to the right of the view increase.
>
> If the autoresizing behaviors do not offer the precise layout that you
>   need for your views, you can use a custom container view and override
>   its layoutSubviews method to position your subviews more precisely.

So if you would like to position a view anchored to the top and right side of its superview, you might apply a mask like:

```
[myView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

Answer (score 1):

superview has such parameters as *contentMode* and *autoresizesSubviews*, wich all with *autoresizingMask* of its subviews makes resizing behavior

read attentively http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I scratched my head for an hour because my one-line UILabel just would NOT auto-adjust font size to fit width. Finally, this did the trick:

```
label.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

I googled and no one seems to clarify this detail (everyone tells you the label should be 1 line, set adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth/minimumFontSize etc.). 
Perhaps this property's default value changed? I'm on iOS 4.3.