# iPhone autoresizingmasks

Tags: iphone, uiview, autoresizingmask

I've been experiencing problems with designing views so that the subviews behave the way I want when using autoresizingmasks (for example, if the status bar size changes, when using the phone as a hotspot etc.). Is there any good documentation that I should definitely read? Apple documents don't seem to help me at least not without some heavy testing of my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that can be a bit complicated to figure out from docs and trial-and-error, but once you get it you'll wonder why you found it so confusing in the first place. I would:

1. Read [Handling Layout Changes Automatically Using Autoresizing Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5) from the View Programming Guide.
2. Play with the springs and struts in the Size inspector in Interface Builder. Putting a horizontal spring inside the box is equivalent to setting `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` (and similarly for height). Putting a strut on top of the box is equivalent to turning `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` **off** (and similarly for the bottom, left, and right margins).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`, is equivalent to setting the width spring, plus both the left and right struts in Interface Builder (the struts mean that the edge is not flexible). If you wanted to replicate the behavior of only setting the width spring, but not the left and right struts, you would have to set `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` | `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` | `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`

see this url too - http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling

taken from - [UIView Autoresizing Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128961/uiview-autoresizing-resources)

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder on tap "Size inspector" you can choose autoresize mask you want. Also in little square screen it will animation with using autoresize so you can see what option did you set.

Comment: I don't use interface builder (I always code my views), but maybe I should try it out as a learning tool.