# How to mark the UIToolBar autoresze when it rotated

Tags: objective-c, ios, toolbar, autoresize

I have created a toolbar. Just like this:

```
    UIToolbar *toolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, toolBarHeight)];

    toolbar.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    UIBarButtonItem *itemNull=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *item0=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self action:@selector(pre)] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *item1=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward target:self action:@selector(pre)] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *item2=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(pre)] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *item3=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemReply target:self action:@selector(pre)] 
        autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *item4=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(pre)] autorelease];
    itemNull.width=frame.size.width-itemwidth*5;
    item0.width=itemwidth;
    item1.width=itemwidth;
    item3.width=itemwidth;
    item4.width=itemwidth;
    item2.width=itemwidth;

    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: itemNull,item0,item1,item2,item3,item4, nil]];
    [self addSubview:toolbar];
    [toolbar release];
```

It is added to a view. But the items are out of the sign when I rotated the view.
and I want to know how to make it visible and not to reset it's frame.
Did the items have the Property like autoresize?

Comment: Possible duplicate, but see this link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128961/uiview-autoresizing-resources

Comment: Can you show some screen shot to clear the issue?

Answer (score 0):

there is an inbuilt hidden toolbar..

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES]; // i hope its a navigation based application.
```

modify code

```
UIBarButtonItem *itemNull=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *item0=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self action:@selector(pre)] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *item1=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward target:self action:@selector(pre)] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *item2=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(pre)] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *item3=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemReply target:self action:@selector(pre)] 
    autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *item4=[[[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(pre)] autorelease];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: itemNull, item0, item1, item2, item3, item4, nil];
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: it unhides the already available toolbar. [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES]; will show the toolbar.