# IOS resize UI after rotation (Is fill parent possible in IOS)

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, resize, rotation

Is it possible to make textfield or other UI to fill screen width? Something like "match_parent" or "fill_parent" in Android.

[image: for example]
  ..
If not, is it a right solution to use "willRotateToInterfaceOrientation" and every time calculate new size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You should Read [Handling Layout Changes Automatically Using Autoresizing Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5) from the View Programming Guide.

**2)** Check `Size Inspector` in your `Interface Builder`.

Check out these Beautiful Links : 
[iPhone Rotation, View Resizing and Layout Handling](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling)
and
[Understanding UIView autoresizing](http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html) 
with this SO Question : [UIView Autoresizing Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2128961/1603072)

Comment: In this case I have to uncheck "Use Autolayout" and setup it manually. But still how can I resize textfield? autoresizingMask - didn't help me.

Comment: Did you set flexible width on the mask ?